# how to retrieve data from DB using AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to retrieve data from DB to my user Dashboard. User Identify using Contact No.

I run AJAX query to retrieve all adds. its running well.

but I need to retrieve data under his user ID (ContactNo). here I add AJAX code.

```
user data avaiable in AUTH -> {{ Auth::user()->ContactNo }}
```

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  //alert("jquery running");
  getAll();

});

  //getting all rows from the database
    function getAll() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('Myadds', app()->getLocale()) }}',
            type: 'GET',

        })
        .done(function(data) {
      alert("run")
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
             $('#data').append('<tr>')
             $('#data').append('<td>'+val.id+'</td>')
             $('#data').append('<td>'+val.Sdescription+'</td>')
             $('#data').append('<td>'+val.created_at+'</td>')
             $('#data').append('<td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="'+val.id+'">Delete</button><button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-id="'+val.id+'">Edit</button></td>')
             $('#data').append('</tr>')
        });
        })
        .fail(function() {
      alert("fail")
            console.log("error");
        })

    }

</script>
```

Comment: what's the issue you're facing exactly? also you should change the outer single quotes to double quotes in the url key.

Comment: all data retrieveing, but I need to filter it using userID (contactNo)

Comment: if you're trying to filter the data based on the authenticated user, then that's a laravel thing not ajax, unless I'm missing something. can you past your action's code?

Comment: as a example, current users userID (contactNo) is 0753505625. ther is so many data fields in DB, so I need pick data field that own to 0753505625. I think I have to pass some data to DB to pick that data. I ask how to pass it using ajax to laravel controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function Myadds(){

        try{
            return add::where('userID', Auth::user()->ContactNo)->get();  


        }catch(Exception $e){
            return 'false';
        }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass de contactNo parameter in your query:

```js
  function getAll() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('Myadds', app()->getLocale()) }}',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { 
              contact_no: contactNo, 
            },
        })
        .done(function(data) {
        alert("run")
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
             $('#data').append('<tr>')
             $('#data').append('<td>'+val.id+'</td>')
             $('#data').append('<td>'+val.Sdescription+'</td>')
             $('#data').append('<td>'+val.created_at+'</td>')
             $('#data').append('<td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="'+val.id+'">Delete</button><button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-id="'+val.id+'">Edit</button></td>')
             $('#data').append('</tr>')
        });
        })
        .fail(function() {
      alert("fail")
            console.log("error");
        })

    }
```

So in your controller now you can filter:

```js
public function getData(Request $request){
     $contact_no = $request->contact_no; 
     
     $query = DB::table('my_table');
     
     if($contact_no){
        $query->where('contact_no',$contact_no)
     }
     
    return response()->json($query->get());
}
```

Or directly use the session of the user:

```js
public function getData(Request $request){
     $contact_no = Auth::user()->ContactNo; 
     
     $query = DB::table('my_table');
     
     $query->where('contact_no',$contact_no)

    return response()->json($query->get());
}
```